# I need some quick factoring tips and tricks

Tags: induction

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 = \frac {n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$.

Define $ p(n)=0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2$. Then:
\begin{align*}p(n + 1)&=0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 + (n + 1)^2\\
&= \frac {n(n + 1)(2n + 1) + 6(n + 1)^2}{6}\\
&= \dots\\
&= \frac {(n + 1) (n + 2)(2n + 3)}{6}
\end{align*}

How do I quickly manipulate $\displaystyle \frac {n(n + 1)(2n + 1) + 6(n + 1)^2}{6}$ to end up with $ \displaystyle  \frac {(n + 1) (n + 2)(2n + 3)}{6}$? Any tricks or tips for something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Take $(n+1)$ common from the two terms, multiply, and then again factorise the resulting quadratic by the trinomial technique. Have you learnt how to factorise a quadratic trinomial?If not, a google search on factorising trinomials would be a nice thing to do

Comment: What are some general factoring techniques that are oft used in such situations? Or what are th things that I can look out for in general? Getting from one polynomial form to another is such a pain.

Comment: You have the terms you want to manipulate and the term you want to end up with. You want to preserve the factors in the term you end up with from what you're working with and use everything else to introduce the rest of the factors.

Comment: The trinomial technique is a nice one. For fast working, you've got to learn a lot of stuff, e.g. start with expansions. If you want to get deeper knowledge, go for the remainder and factor theorems for polynomials(helpful for factorising polynomials of degree 3 or larger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about taking common $n+1$ and then adding $$n(2n+1) + 6(n+1) = 2n^2 + 4n + 3n + 6 = (n+2)(2n + 3)$$